# Python Keras Running Error (Invalid Syntax)

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I downladed keras library to python 3.7
But when i want to run my code, i got "invalid sytnax error"

All i did is wrote this

```
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an annoying bug because `async` is a reserved keyword in python3.7.

Go to `C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py` and change these two line

```
def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
    return _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async)
```

to

```
def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, abc):
    return _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, abc)
```

Comment: OK, replace all `async` to something else, beware, only the variable named `async` not the `Async` in function name

Comment: Honestly using python3.6 instead might be a better idea if you don't really need 3.7.

Comment: Or change `tensorflow` version, I'm using 1.14 with python 3.6 and they use `enable` instead of `async`

Answer (score 1):

async is reserved keyword. Just use another name for argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade TensorFlow, the version you are using does not support Python 3.7, later versions have no issue with Python 3.7